# How to set a custom hotkey to open a specific folder

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, settings, customization

I have many folders and many folders in the folders, (my work) I want to be able to save some time on: "open home, open X folder then open Y folder then open Z folder."
I just want to click Shift + Y and open a specific folder I need, without wasting 10 minutes of folder clicking per work day. (also sometimes I forget the location so its another 10 minutes of searching)

Is it possible to program/set a hotkey to open a specific folder?
I tried using the "command" in `settings` -> `Keyboard shortcuts` -> `custom shortcuts`, it didn't work and I couldn't find any info on how to use the command language.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a shortcut key to open a specific folder, define it in "Settings - Keyboard", section "Custom Shortcuts". Use the "+" at the bottom of the list. Enter a command like

```
xdg-open "/home/yourlogin/Documents"
```

And assign the shortcut key.

The example will open the Documents folder of user `yourlogin`. The symbol "~" that, in the terminal, expands to the user's home directory, or bash variables do not work here, so always enter the full path. The quotes are required if your pathname contains spaces or other special characters.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked "xdg-open "/home/user/X folder/Y folder".